# How to access the values of error response from subscribe

Tags: angular

```
this.reg.registerUser(user).subscribe(
      (res) => {
          this.registered = res ? true : false;
          this.loading = false;
          console.log(res);
          this.registerForm.reset();
      },
      (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          this.err = err;
      }
   );
```

This is what err looks like in console.log (Image)
[err in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPicy.png)

I want to check if there is an error from the backend api when registering so that i can use it in form validation, if the email already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the mesage with dot operator

```
this.err = err.error.email[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you return object from your API include error message?
Example { Result: true/false, Message: "Your message" }